# How to describe an array of objects in URL query params using swagger?

Tags: php, url, swagger, openapi

I'm developing a web service with OpenAPI 3.0.0. Basically, I want to create an endpoint which does some magic when I send an HTTP POST request there.

The problem is that I need to pass some params in a URL query string in a form of `http://example.com/create?custom_extras[0][name]=Bob&custom_extras[0][price_id]=1&custom_extras[0][duration]=0`.

To be more precise I have a problem with `custom_extras[0][name]=Bob&custom_extras[0][price_id]=1&custom_extras[0][duration]=0`. As a matter of fact I need here an **array** of **objects**.

**Example**:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "price_id": 42,
    "duration": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Sam",
    "price_id": 43,
    "duration": 0
  }
]
```

I've created a specification with swagger which gives me `http://example.com/creata?custom_extras[0]={"name": "Bob", "price_id": 42, "duration": 0}"&custom_extras[1]={"name": "Sam", "price_id": 43, "duration": 0}"`

However, what I really want is to have something similar to this `http://example.com/creata?custom_extras[0][name]=Bob&custom_extras[0][price_id]=42&custom_extras[0][duration]=0&custom_extras[1][name]=Sam&custom_extras[1][price_id]=43&custom_extras[1][duration]=0`

I was wondering if it is possible to create the URL of the form I described above? Thanks.

Here is swagger I used.

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  description: "Example"
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "Example"
paths:
  /create:
    post:
      tags:
      - example
      summary: Example
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: custom_extras
          required: false
          style: deepObject
          explode: true
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: object
              additionalProperties:
                type: object
                properties:
                  name: 
                    type: string
                  price_id:
                    type: integer
                  duration:
                    type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```

Comment: @Helen it looks like you've just posted the answer to my question. Thanks, I'll close my post.